# Modal on react not working properly - Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a react shopping page. Redux is used for store management. On my home page I have 2 buttons against each shopping product. On clicking detail button I need to display a modal/popup with corresponding product details from store. I managed to display the modal with details, but modal is displaying details of my first product for every buttons instead of the respective product details(As you seen in the image. For every button the first product details of initial state is getting displayed). Could anyone sort out this issue.(I am new to js and react)
[image]
Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from './actions/cartAction'

class Home extends Component{

render(){

    let itemList = this.props.items.map(item=>{
        return(
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 bttm-pad">
                <div class="card " key={item.id} >
                    <img class="card-img-top" src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{item.title}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{item.desc}</p>
                            <p class="card-text "><b>Price: <span class="WebRupee">&#x20B9; 
                                                               </span> {item.price}</b></p>
                            
                            <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  
                            class="btn btn-primary ">Detail</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>{ this.props.addToCart(item.id)}} >Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
    let modalList = this.props.items.map(modal=>{
        return(
            <div class="modal" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Product Detail</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 text-center">
                                <img src={modal.img} alt="Product Image" class="img-fluid z-depth-1-half rounded"/>
                                <div style={{height: 10}}></div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-9 text-left">
                                <p><strong>{modal.title}</strong></p>
                                <p class="card-text text-left">
                                {modal.desc}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

            )
        })

    return(

        <div className="container">
            <div className="row home-head">
                <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1><strong>Store Items</strong></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className= "row">
                
                {itemList}
                {modalList}
                
     </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}
    
}    

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
return {
    items: state.items
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps= (dispatch)=>{
return{
addToCart: (id)=>{dispatch(addToCart(id))}
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

cartReducer.js

```
const initState = {
items: [
    {id:1,title:'Winter body', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:15510,img:Item1},
    {id:2,title:'Jordan Delta 2', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:11150,img: Item2},
    {id:3,title:'Nike Air Force 1 07', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.",price:8199,img: Item3},
    {id:4,title:'KD14 EP', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:13490,img:Item4},
    {id:5,title:'Nike ACG Mountain Fly', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.", price:16595,img: Item5},
    {id:6,title:'Nike Air Vapormax Evo SE', desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, ex.",price:17999,img: Item6}
],
addedItems:[],
total: 0

}
const cartReducer= (state = initState,action)=>{
 if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART){
    let addedItem = state.items.find(item=> item.id === action.id)
    let existed_item= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
        
        if(existed_item)
            {
                addedItem.quantity += 1 
                return{
                    ...state,
                    total: state.total + addedItem.price 
                }
            }
        else{
                addedItem.quantity = 1;
                let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price 
                return{
                    ...state,
                    addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
                    total : newTotal
                    }
        
            }
}

else{
    return state
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating repeated same modalId for every toggle and modal:

```
<a
  type="button"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#myModal"
  class="btn btn-primary "
>
Detail
</a>
```

And

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
```

So when you click an a tag with a modalId it will show the first found modal with the same id in that tag.
To make your current code works, you will need to have uniqueId for every a tag and modal.

**However this is not a great way to show modal for each product**

You are making React render way too many unnecessary DOM nodes, too many modals in your case.

I strongly recommend you to create another component for that modal, then pass props from your selected product and show it accordingly. That way you don't make React render unnecessary DOM nodes.

Comment: Got it

<a
type="button"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target= {'#'+item.id}
class="btn btn-primary "
>
Detail
</a>
And

<div class="modal" id={item.id}>